# spring integration outbound gateway sax parse exception

Tags: spring

I am getting an exception Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 198 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 198; columnNumber: 88; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-ws:outbound-gateway'.:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 198; columnNumber: 88; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-ws:outbound-gateway'.

The xml file looks like

I have added the relevant xsds also. Any clue.

Answer (score 0):

Could help:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd >
```